# New to Shopify, can't get "Sort By" menu to sort by prices properly

Tags: jquery, sorting, shopify, liquid

I am working with a new site and am using Shopify for the first time. Pretty neat program, but I'm having some issues with adding a 'Sort By' drop-down menu.

I'm using the drop-down menu from this link:

https://gist.github.com/carolineschnapp/11352987

However, I've run into issues when I sort by prices. Here is the HTML code for a typical product on my page:

```
<div class="product span2">

   <div class="image">
      <a href="/collections/beers-in-stock/products/woodchuck-amber-cider">
      <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/Woodchuck_Amber_6PK_12OZ_BTL_medium.jpg?v=1404322721" alt="Woodchuck Amber Cider">
      </a>
   </div>

   <div class="details">
      <a href="/collections/beers-in-stock/products/woodchuck-amber-cider" class="clearfix">

         <span class="">
            <h4 class="title">Woodchuck Amber Cider</h4>
            <del>$10.49</del>
            $9.99
         </span>
      </a>  
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant script from the drop-down menu page:

```
<script>
   Shopify.queryParams = {};
   if (location.search.length) {
     for (var aKeyValue, i = 0, aCouples = location.search.substr(1).split('&'); i < aCouples.length; i++) {
       aKeyValue = aCouples[i].split('=');

       if (aKeyValue.length > 1) {
         Shopify.queryParams[decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[0])] = decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[1]);
       }
     }
   }

   jQuery('#sort-by')
     .val('{{ collection.sort_by | default: collection.default_sort_by | escape }}')
     .bind('change', function() {
       Shopify.queryParams.sort_by = jQuery(this).val();
       location.search = jQuery.param(Shopify.queryParams).replace(/\+/g, '%20');
     });
</script>
```

I think that **the issue has something to do with products that contain struckthrough prices before showing the new, lower price.** These struckthrough prices (marked by the  tags) seem to confuse the sorting algorithm, as it groups them all together as having the lowest possible price.

I'm not very familiar with Shopify, so I'm really sure how to correct this sorting issue.

I've included some pictures to show how it sorts them. In these examples, the products are all sorted by 'Prices: Lowest to Highest'.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN7fh.jpg

As you can see, these are definitely not sorted from the lowest price to the highest and I really need to figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there on line demo (the website you are talking about), I think if you put we can figure out the problem